# Data transfer from raspberry pi to my computer using ssh

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to capture accelerometer data using a raspberry pi and then do some analysis on it. I am wondering how can I stream that data into my computer from the pi using SSH. FYI i am using a mac.

Comment: You can just use a socket. Practice at commandline with `netcat` also known as `nc` - dead simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can not stream your data using only SSH. Instead. You can send data to your Mac using TCP. Write a programmer to open a TCP server and receive data. Then send data from RPI on that TCP channel.